# Update Single out of multiple nodes in XML

Tags: xml, oracle11g, toad

I need to update the daysworked for Russ from 21 to 22 but unable to find code where I can reach only that node to update based on the condition.

Even if I extract , it gives me only first node's data.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(XMLDATA,  'root/Level1Users/employeeinfo/username')
    FROM TblUser_DATA -- gives only first username

SELECT EXTRACT(XMLDATA,  'root/Level1Users/employeeinfo/username/text()')
        FROM TblUser_DATA -- returns concatenated usernames in single row
```

Any pointers ?

```
<root>
  <Level1Users>
    <isTrue>false</isTrue>
    <employeeinfo>
    <username>Tissy</username>
    <role>RES</role>
     <daysworked>20</daysworked>
    <availability/>
    </employeeinfo>
    <employeeinfo>
    <username>Russ</username>
    <role>PES</role>
     <daysworked>21</daysworked>
    <availability>Yes</availability>
   </employeeinfo>
  <employeeinfo>
    <username>Amy</username>
    <role>PES</role>
     <daysworked>22</daysworked>
    <availability>Yes</availability>
   </employeeinfo>
    <by>ABC</by>
    <date>13-JUN-2017</date>
  </Level1Users>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with abc as (select xmltype('<root>
  <Level1Users>
    <isTrue>false</isTrue>
    <employeeinfo>
    <username>Tissy</username>
    <role>RES</role>
     <daysworked>20</daysworked>
    <availability/>
    </employeeinfo>
    <employeeinfo>
    <username>Russ</username>
    <role>PES</role>
     <daysworked>21</daysworked>
    <availability>Yes</availability>
   </employeeinfo>
  <employeeinfo>
    <username>Amy</username>
    <role>PES</role>
     <daysworked>22</daysworked>
    <availability>Yes</availability>
   </employeeinfo>
    <by>ABC</by>
    <date>13-JUN-2017</date>
  </Level1Users>
</root>') xml_ from dual)
select 
          xmlquery('copy $doc :=. modify
               ( for $i in $doc/root/Level1Users/employeeinfo
                 where $i/username/text() eq "Russ"
                 return replace value of node $i/daysworked with "22")
                 return $doc'
                           passing xml_ returning content)
```

How it's work. 
`Xmlquery( 'xquery statement' passing {list of passed element } returning content)` -> function returns `xmltype`

`copy $doc :=. modify` - copy full `$input_document` to variable `$doc`. (we can modify only copy of  input_docuemnt)
`(for ... return )` it is 'flwor expression ' f - for, l-let, w-where, o-order.
Expression means. For each `employeeinfo` where `employeeinfo/username/test() = 'Russ'` replaca value of node `employeeinfo/daysworked with '22'` and return new xml document outside `return $doc`.

To update you have to utilize xmlquery in update statement.

```
Update table set xml_column := xmlquery('xquery' passing xml_column returning content)
```